# how to create subdomain by .htaccess on rewrite directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have created a subdomain with this .htaccess; it is working fine on my www.example.com domain but not on www.example.pk. I do not understand where the problem is.

**www.example.com**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/*([0-9]+)*$ index.php?r=list&source=product&product_get=%1&page_page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**www.example.pk**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.pk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.pk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/*([0-9]+)*$ index.php?r=list&source=product&product_get=%1&page_page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I created www.example.com domain then the subdomain with cpanel *.example.com. Is it necessary or not?

Comment: Does the server listen to the subdomain in the first place (vHost or however it is configured)?

Comment: when i configure this method on www.example.pk domain then this error appears "Problem Loading Page" but working fine on www.example.com domain; both domains are hosted on same hosting

Comment: Can oyu give us the real domain names to check?

Comment: (I'm asking because the issue is clearly not the .htaccess file, they're identical, it's impossible one works and one doesn't.)

Comment: have you got my domain or can we chat is it possible?

Comment: there are NO DNS entries for markaz.pk...

Comment: (and you don't have enough reputation to talk in chat)

Answer (score 0):

When you work with subdomains, you need to configure your DNS correctly to direct subdomains to your server. The subdomain-feature of cpanel might have done this for you, or it already contained a wildcard cname dns record. DNS records are usually cached, but I am unsure if this is the case for non-existing records too.

**Does the subdomain already resolve to my server?**

First check if your subdomain already resolves to an ip. Open a terminal and type `ping yoursubdomain.example.com` (obviously you need to replace this with your actual domain). If it can't be resolved to an ip, then there is probably a problem with your DNS record. You can do that online if you want [here](http://viewdns.info/ping/) or on several other, similar, sites.

**Editing your dns**

If your host gives you an opportunity to edit the DNS records manually, you'll need to know the following:

- There is 1 A-record in your dns. This is how the name is translated to an ip.
- Any subdomains are linked to that record using CNAME-records.

You can either add a wildcard-subdomain (which will translate any (un)thinkable subdomain to your site) or a specific subdomain to your dns. You do so by adding

```
CNAME  (from) *.example.com (to) example.com
```

The TTL (time to live) is how long a record can be cached by others. It will, at most, take TTL to get everyone in the world to 'notice' changes you make in a record of your dns. [This site](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/dns/cname-records/) gives some more information about that.

**.htaccess**

I am not sure what kind of urls you want to rewrite, but there are a couple of things you can change:

- `%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with a `/`. There is no need to add a `?` behind it in your condition.
- For readability, if you use `%1`-type-of-backreferences, put the corresponding condition directly above it, even if it turns out they are not overwritten by other conditions without capture groups.
- `^(.*)/*([0-9]+)*$` doesn't make much sense to me. It matches every url, because everything after `(.*)` is optional, and can be there an infinite amount of times. I doubt this is what you wanted it to be.

---

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.pk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example\.pk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/*([0-9]+)*$ index.php?r=list&source=product&product_get=%1&page_page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you for answer; i would not do wildcard subdomain; i want to do with .htaccess i have already done on my www.mydomain.com but when i try to apply on www.mydomain.pk it's not work; i dont know where is problem. have you any solution?

Comment: Have you followed the text under "Does the subdomain already resolve to my server?"? What is the outcome?

Comment: please don't shout at us. as I already told you, the .htaccess file is clearly not the issue. You CANNOT implement subdomains with .htaccess only, you always need DNS entries, too (you need both, DNS entries and server-side configuration). DNS is necessary,so that computer know whcih server to aks for the content, the server config is necessary to tell the server it is responsible for that domain.

Comment: @user3340947 Say you have a tablet (DNS), and would get horribly lost if you would set a step outside your house without it. Your tablet tells you exactly how to navigate from your house to a given location. You ask your tablet: "Give me directions to Googlestreet 1". And it shows you exactly where you go. At Googlestreet 1 (a server), the personel will show you around further. Back home you try the same thing for "MySubdomain 1". The tablet however says: "I don't know this address". I am sure that the personel at MySubdomain 1 would gladly help you further, *but you are unable to get there!*